# Unexpected diagnostic with a class/function template combination

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have created a class template that defines a 2D vector type, where the members have variable data types.

```
template<class Type> struct XY
{
    Type X, Y;
    XY() {}
    XY(Type X, Type Y): X(X), Y(Y)
    Type Square() const { return (X * X + Y * Y); }
};
```

In addition, I overload the minus operator and define an extra `S` function.

```
template<class Type> XY<Type> operator-(const Type& P, const Type& Q)
{ return XY<Type>(P.X - Q.X, P.Y - Q.Y); }
template<class Type> Type S(const XY<Type>& P, const XY<Type>& Q)
{ return (P - Q).Square(); }
```

Now the code below doesn't compile, under VS2008:

```
void main()
{
    struct XY<int> P, Q;
    S(P, Q);
}
```

What puzzles me most is the error message, saying

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'XY<Type>' to 'int'
```

at the line defining the function `S`.

The result of the subtraction is clearly a `struct XY` and the method `Square` applied to it returns a scalar, which doesn't require any conversion.

Any explanation ?

Comment: You show `template<class Type> Type S(const XY<Type>& P, const XY<Type>& Q)` but you call `Square(P, Q);`.  Is that right? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver: of course this is right, otherwise there would be infinite recursion (note that I am calling `(P - Q).Square()`). I couldn't provide a more minimal/minimal example.

Comment: Your example might be minimal but it isn't complete.  Can you give us something we can copy and paste right into a compiler?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'll wrap with a main program to please you.

Comment: Dont you mean `template<class Type> XY<Type> operator-(const XY<Type>& P, const XY<Type>& Q)` instead of `template<class Type> XY<Type> operator-(const Type& P, const Type& Q)` ?

Comment: `void` main is not legal in C++. Also, fix your syntax errors. The `main` you added is ill-formed (Square doesn't take any arguments and it is a member function of `XY`). Otherwise, the code is fine.

Comment: @AndreasH.: oops, yes. I have been staring at the code for hours and didn't see it. You can turn this to an answer, thanks !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I am glad I could help.

Comment: @AndyG: `void main` is a Microsoft specific extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean

```
template<class Type> XY<Type> operator-(const XY<Type>& P, const XY<Type>& Q)
```

instead of

```
template<class Type> XY<Type> operator-(const Type& P, const Type& Q)
```

The latter is apparently not called. In function `S` the compiler tries to call the builtin `operator -` for `int` and hence tries to convert the arguments `P` and `Q` to convert to `int` (which is not possible and hence the error).